# Java GridLayout Manager in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager, grid-layout

NetBeans IDE 7.4 is not recognizing `GridLayout` Manager gives an error:

```
no suitable method found for setLayout(GridLayout)     
  method Container.setLayout(LayoutManager) is not applicable       
    (argument mismatch; GridLayout cannot be converted to LayoutManager)     
  method JFrame.setLayout(LayoutManager) is not applicable       
    (argument mismatch; GridLayout cannot be converted to LayoutManager)
```

Do you know what could be wrong? I have uninstalled and reinstalled JDK and IDE to no avail. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to resolve all imports.

Works perfectly fine for me. You might be forgetting to instantiate.

The only other think I can see happening is that you have defined your own `GridLayout` class withing the same package, and that `GridLayout` is *not* a `LayoutManager`

Comment: That just remove my awt.* import. It didn't change the error. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Is it possible you created another `GridLayout` class in the same package? As practice or something?

Comment: The class was named GridLayout, I refactored the class to GridLayout1 and it is accepting it now. Thanks